# PDF encrypted with PHP openssl and decrypted in Java Android studio not opening

Tags: java, php, android, pdf, encryption

I have an android app, which requests a an encrypted file from server and stores it to files directory of the app, the pdfs are listed in the app and opens the pdf after decrypting the pdf when clicked. I am successfully able to encrypt the file on the server and decrypt the file on the app as the strings looks same. But after converting the decrypted string into a pdf file, the app cannot open the file, or the android system cannot open the files, says corrupted format.

**PHP function to encrypt the file:**

```
function encFile($data){
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16,$secure);
  if (false === $iv) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('iv generation failed');
  }

  $data = $iv . openssl_encrypt($data, 'AES-128-CBC', 'RfTjWnZr4u7x!A%D', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
  $data=base64_encode($data);
  //echo $data;
  return $data;
}
```

**After getting the encrypted string:**

```
$encData=encFile($data);
$fullFileName="EncFiles/temp".time().".pdf";
file_put_contents($fullFileName, $encData);
```

**Java function which decrypts it and makes a pdf file:**

```
private void decFile(String fileLocation) throws IOException {
        //File to String
        File encFile=new File(fileLocation);
        InputStream inputStream=null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(encFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        boolean done = false;

        while (!done) {
            String line=null;
            try {
                line = reader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            done = (line == null);

            if (line != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        }

        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        inputStream.close();

        String encString=stringBuilder.toString();
        Log.i("encString",encString);
        //Start Decryption

        byte[] data64= android.util.Base64.decode(encString, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        if(data64.length < 17) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Something went Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Log.i("decString",data64+"");
        byte[] ivBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(data64, 0, 16);
        byte[] contentBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(data64, 16, data64.length);
        Log.i("decString",contentBytes+"");
        try {
            Cipher ciper = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            String temp=getDecKey();

            SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(temp.getBytes("UTF-8"),"AES");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes,0, ciper.getBlockSize());

            ciper.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, iv);
            byte[] decString=ciper.doFinal(contentBytes);

            //Bytes to string
//            String s= new String(decString);
//            Log.i("decRYPTED STRING",s);
            //Bytes to File;
            long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();

            long seconds = millis / 1000;
            String path=this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/decFile_"+seconds+".pdf";
            Log.i("PATH",path);
            File decFile = new File(path);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(decFile));
            bos.write(decString);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            Log.i("DEC",decFile.getAbsoluteFile().toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,PDFWebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("fromOffline",1);
            intent.putExtra("filelocation",decFile.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (
                NoSuchAlgorithmException |
                        NoSuchPaddingException |
                        UnsupportedEncodingException |
                        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException |
                        InvalidKeyException |
                        IllegalBlockSizeException |
                        BadPaddingException ignored
        ) {
            //ignored.printStackTrace();
            ignored.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am using pdf.js and webview to view the pdf. Please help me solve the issue.

Edit: 
Took reference from https://gist.github.com/Haehnchen/3cb18c40fea2ab883ef1a7a8e25422dc

Comment: If the ciphertext decrypts then there is a one in 256 possibly that it is the wrong data (the chance that unpadding fails for a wrong key / ciphertext combination or altered ciphertext of the correct size). So it is unlikely that the problem lies in the encryption / decryption, it is much more probable that the binary input of the PHP code itself is mangled somehow.

Comment: thanks for everyone who tried, the mistake was mine. The problem was with the pdfviewer which was not able to display it as the view as set to invisible,

Comment: anyone who wants to use it https://github.com/rohit267/php-encrypt-java-android-decrypt-file

Comment: I'm not sure that's already fit for sharing, Rohit. It's very raw, no good exception handling, no streaming of files, uses the old CBC instead of GCM etc.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes i will look forward to use GCM, thank you